# Process sequential row pairs with numpy

Tags: numpy

I have an (NxK) array, and I need to efficiently calculate differences between sequential row pairs, producing an (N-1 x K) array (i.e. elements in its first column would be calculated as A[i+1,0]-A[i,0]). Is it possible to do this not with a loop (which is obvious), but in a more elegant vectorized way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) does exactly that with its parameter `axis`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> np.diff(a, axis = 0)
array([[3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3]])
>>> np.diff(a, axis=1)
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be something simple and convenient that I missed in the docs :-)

Answer (score 1):

or using slices:

```
a[1:,:] - a[:-1,:]
```